# Why were Colonel Cathcart and Colonel Korn so determined to undermine each other?

Tags: character-analysis, catch-22, joseph-heller

In *Catch-22*, both Colonel Cathcart and Colonel Korn seem bound and determined to undermine each other. I know both of them are desperately trying to get promoted (to the point of doing absolutely absurd things to do so), but why such schadenfreude on their parts when the other experienced some kind of misfortune? Do they see promotion as some "zero-sum game" where they can only "win" at the other's expense?

Comment: It’s not enough that they’re rivals?

Comment: @AE That seems vaguely circular to me (or at least "turtles all the way down") - you'd then have to ask why they were rivals, which doesn't really seem all *that* different than asking why they were trying to undermine each other.

Comment: Roughly speaking, there are three or four lieutenants for each captain, three or four captains for each major, etc. Hard not to feel that one's promotion depended on the failures of one's rivals! Supposedly a common toast among the junior officers in the old British navy was, "Here's to a bloody war or a sickly season!".